# How android root(/) mount system partition on /system with 'mount' program on system partition?

Tags: android, linux, kernel, boot, mount

As we know, at stage of init process launch during the Android boot, it'll finish the filesystem populating. Android takes use of a ramdisk as root('/') with less useful stuffs on it but put nearly all binary programs and libraries into a partition named 'system' which would be mounted on '/system' directory by init. But I'm curious about the fact that the 'mount' program itself resides on system partition's 'bin' directory, so, 'mount' system partition on /system needs '/system/bin/mount' works first! How would it be done? This seems a chicken and egg question.
ps. I only found 'sbin' directory under '/' that contains adbd and uevent two programs only.

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question title - it makes no sense to another reader, and try to format your question text, so that your actual question stands out.

Comment: I think there is a copy of mount in the initrd.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not native English speaker, and it's the first time that I use stackoverflow asking tech questions, sorry for my foolish. But I think I have know the answer, it's the kernel that mount /system, /cache, /data partitions, for kernel has hardcoded all them addresses into MTD_PARTITION table, so kernel knows how to mount them, in stead of init process to do it

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase your question:

- *In order to mount /system partition, we need "mount" command in first place. Most command utilities (binary or symbolic links), however, reside in /system partition which is not mounted yet*

My answer :

- *Even though a lot of init's commands resemble command-line equivalents lents from Toolbox or elsewhere, init will NOT attempt to issue commands to the command line. init actually includes a slew of commands as part of its lexicon.*

Comment: Thanks very much, you understand me totally. I recognize my foolish after I am pointed out the _mount_ is actually a system call provided by OS